# How to putAll on Java hashMap contents of one to another, but not replace existing keys and values?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I need to copy all keys and values from one A HashMap onto another one B, but not to replace existing keys and values.

Whats the best way to do that?

I was thinking instead iterating the keySet and checkig if it exist or not, I would

```
Map temp = new HashMap(); // generic later
temp.putAll(Amap);
A.clear();
A.putAll(Bmap);
A.putAll(temp);
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It looks like you are willing to create a temporary `Map`, so I'd do it like this:

```
Map tmp = new HashMap(patch);
tmp.keySet().removeAll(target.keySet());
target.putAll(tmp);
```

Here, `patch` is the map that you are adding to the `target` map.

Thanks to [Louis Wasserman,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) here's a version that takes advantage of the new methods in Java 8:

```
patch.forEach(target::putIfAbsent);
```

Comment: In this case you don't need to do `removeAll` since they'll get overriden anyways.

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo: Overwritten by what?

Comment: @luksmir No, that would remove the existing entries that should be preserved.

Comment: Hi! Why mapWithValues.putAll(mapWithAnotherValues) doens't work?

Comment: @betomoretti Because if both maps have a value for a key, that would replace the original value with another. That would violate the requirement "not to replace existing keys and values."

Comment: @erickson I messed up the requirement. But , in case of that requirement doesn't exists, it's work? Sorry for my English and thanks!

Comment: @erickson Well, mapWithValues.putAll(mapWithAnotherValues) void mapWithValues. So, this it's not a good solution. In fact, doesn't work.

Comment: @erickson a much more compact Java 8 version: `patch.forEach(target::putIfAbsent)`.

Answer (score 16):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [Maps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) class' utility methods to compute the difference of 2 maps you can do it in a single line, with a method signature which makes it more clear what you are trying to accomplish:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // Create some maps
    final Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map1.put(1, "Hello");
    map1.put(2, "There");
    final Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map2.put(2, "There");
    map2.put(3, "is");
    map2.put(4, "a");
    map2.put(5, "bird");

    // Add everything in map1 not in map2 to map2
    map2.putAll(Maps.difference(map1, map2).entriesOnlyOnLeft());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just iterate and add:

```
for(Map.Entry e : a.entrySet())
  if(!b.containsKey(e.getKey())
    b.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Edit to add:

If you can make changes to a, you can also do:

```
a.putAll(b)
```

and a will have exactly what you need. (all the entries in `b` and all the entries in `a` that aren't in `b`)

Comment: 1.) `entrySet()` returns a `Set<Map.Entry>`. 2.) There is no method `contains(...)`for `java.util.Map`.

Comment: Isnt there a smarter way? Like a Collections utility or so? I hate all the for loops everywhere.

Comment: @AntonioP: All the for loops everywhere? There's one for loop and it's about as straightforward as you can get.

Comment: +1 then, just works when Maps used not with raw type, I think. Got myself a bit fuddled with the Map.Entry :-)

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo, ah, elsewhere in the code. :)
Wont .putAll replace existing keys and values of a?
Ill go with this sense it does seem the most straightforward way.

Comment: @AntonioP, if you want to do something custom you can't avoid custom code (like looping).

Comment: I guess this is better for performance than to create a whole new map?

Answer (score 6):

You can make it in just 1 line if you change maps order in @erickson's solution:

```
mapWithNotSoImportantValues.putAll( mapWithImportantValues );
```

In this case you replace values in mapWithNotSoImportantValues with value from mapWithImportantValues with the same keys.

Answer (score 5):

#### Java 8 solution using `Map#merge`

As of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you can use [`Map#merge(K key, V value, BiFunction remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which merges a value into the `Map` using `remappingFunction` in case the key is already found in the `Map` you want to put the pair into.

```
// using lambda
newMap.forEach((key, value) -> map.merge(key, value, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));
```

```
// using for-loop
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: newMap.entrySet()) {
    map.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue);
}
```

The code iterates the `newMap` entries (`key` and `value`) and each one is merged into `map` through the method `merge`. The `remappingFunction` is triggered in case of duplicated key and in that case it says that the former (original) `oldValue` value will be used and not rewritten.

With this solution, you don't need a temporary `Map`.

---

Let's have an example of merging `newMap` entries into `map` and keeping the original values in case of the duplicated antry.

```
Map<Integer, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
newMap.put(2, "EVIL VALUE");                         // this will NOT be merged into
newMap.put(4, "four");                               // this WILL be merged into
newMap.put(5, "five");                               // this WILL be merged into

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "one");
map.put(2, "two");
map.put(3, "three");

newMap.forEach((k, v) -> map.merge(k, v, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));

map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

> ```
> 1 one
> 2 two
> 3 three
> 4 four
> 5 five
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key1", "value1");
    map1.put("key2", "value2");
    map1.put("key3", "value3");
    map1.put(null, null);

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("key4", "value4");
    map2.put("key5", "value5");
    map2.put("key6", "value6");
    map2.put("key3", "replaced-value-of-key3-in-map2");
    // used only if map1 can be changes/updates with the same keys present in map2.
    map1.putAll(map2);

    // use below if you are not supposed to modify the map1.
    for (Map.Entry e : map2.entrySet())
        if (!map1.containsKey(e.getKey()))
            map1.put(e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString());
    System.out.println(map1);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 there is this API method to accomplish your requirement.

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, value)
```

If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null) associates it with the given value and returns null, else returns the current value.

Comment: can we have putAllIfAbsent ? thats what I need ?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can use `putIfAbsent`. Iterate over each entry in the map that you want to insert, and invoke this method on the original map:

```
mapToInsert.forEach(originalMap::putIfAbsent);
```