# Update all values at a time in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` with some `Keys - Values`.

On some condition I want to update **all** values to single value regardless of keys.

Is there any util or predefined methods to do this, without for loop?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can you not use a for loop?

Comment: What's so bad about `for` loop? I haven't heard of any utils like that. Anyway if there are any, they are most likely to contain a loop inside.

Comment: Not in JDK, and I don't suppose you prefer adding a whole new JAR to your project just to avoid writing this one-liner.

Comment: In particular, *something* is going to have to loop - and you only have to write the (tiny) method once...

Comment: not that i know of.  i beljeve you will have to use a loop.  shouldn't be too complex, for loop on Hash.getKeys().

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change all values in a `HashMap` without a loop. I think your best shot is to use the `entrySet()` method with a for-each loop. This method is highly optimized and easy to use.

Comment: Afterwards, do the values need to be independent?

Comment: Make sure every key in your HashMap points to the same object, et voila!

Comment: I think that the only purpose of this question is to downvote the answerers. It should be actually closed as not constructive.

Comment: thanks for all your replys.

Comment: I think this question needs to be edited (mention of "no loop" should be removed) and reopened. 10k views is a sign that people stumble upon this problem a lot.

Comment: BTW, since Java 8 the ideomatic way to do this is calling `Map.replaceAll((k, v) -> myConstantValue)`

Answer (score 19):

```
if (yourCondition) { 
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
          map.put(entry.getKey(), MY_VALUE);
      }
}
```

Or for java 8 or higher (without a loop)

```
if (yourCondition) { 
      map.replaceAll( (k,v)->v=MY_VALUE );
}
```

Comment: why `-`? I'll happily delete or edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: Someone passed by and downvoted the whole room ;)

Comment: I think this got -1 because of OP clearly said: "without for loop"

Comment: It's really bad to downvote without mentioning why. I hate it, +1 (Although the OP said "without for loop".. -1 without mentioning why is not valid).....

Comment: Note that if the underlying `Map` implementation supports it, you can just call `entry.setValue(MY_VALUE)`.

Comment: Well whatever! this helped me, looking for an easy solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterator on *entrySet*:

```
Iterator it = yourMap.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry keyValue;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    keyValue = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    //Now you can have the keys and values and easily replace the values...
}
```

Note that the internal implementation of the iterator still uses a for loop :)

Comment: Serial downvoter - Why?

Comment: Note - I didn't downvote. However, this 500+ answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map) indicates another, perhaps `cleaner?` way, to iterate over a map.

Comment: OP: "*without for loop?*" - I thought he wants to use an iterator. I hate it to be downvoted without mentioning why. I want to learn from my mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Collections2.transform(stringStringHashMap.values(), new Function<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public String apply(java.lang.String s) {
    return "modified string";
  }
});
```

Comment: Does `apply()` work like `map` in Haskell?

Comment: thanks for all your replys

Comment: @Kevin: That part is just boilerplate since Java doesn't have lambda expressions, so you have to make an anonymous class and implement the `apply()` method instead. The important bit here is `transform()`, which is indeed like Haskell's `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the HashMap and make your implementation return your magic value if some condition is set.

Comment: Extending the entire `HashMap` seems like overkill. Why is it necessary to extend it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "entire hashmap" but overriding the get-method & other value acquirers would allow the implementation return the same value for any key (or the actual value for the key) based on some condition - this achieves the same behaviour as replacing all values. It clearly is not the same thing as actually replacing all values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you plan to set it to a single value, but you can call `putAll` on the `HashMap` as demonstrated from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194914/195488):

```
Map tmp = new HashMap(patch);
tmp.keySet().removeAll(target.keySet());
target.putAll(tmp);
```

`patch` is the `map` you are adding to `target`.

`patch` could be a `HashMap` containing the same value for all keys....