# Change every value of a MultiKeyMap (Apache Commons)

Tags: java, apache, loops, iterator, multikey

As part of a larger program I am trying to multiply every value of an Apache Commons `MultiKeyMap` by 120. I think I could use an `Iterator`, but I believe those only work for normal hashmaps.

What I want to do, in terms of arrays, is this:

```
int[] array = { 8, 9, 6, 4, 5 }
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = array[i] * 120;
}
```

I am not sure how to implement something like this with a `MultiKeyMap`. I have looked for solutions, and found a way to iterate a normal `HashMap` ([Update all values at a time in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588492/update-all-values-at-a-time-in-hashmap)):

```
Iterator it = yourMap.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry keyValue;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    keyValue = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    //Now you can have the keys and values and easily replace the values...
}
```

However, this works only for a simple `<K, V>` map, where I have `<K, K, K, V>`. How could I do this with a `MultiKeyMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiKeyMap` still supports iterators, see the docs:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html#mapIterator()

```
MapIterator it = multiKeyMap.mapIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
    System.out.println(it.getValue());
}
```