# how to copy one hashmap content to another hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Here I have two hashmaps `dataz` and `screen_dataz`. I want to copy `screen_dataz` to `dataz`.

I am trying like this but it's not working:

```
Object[]  obj = new Object[5];
String[] strArray = new String[]{"Obj1","Array1","Converted1","To1","List1"};
String[] strArray1 = new String[]{"Obj2","Array2","Converted2","To2","List2"};
dataz.put(0,(Object[]) strArray);
dataz.put(1,(Object[]) strArray1);
// String dataString = (String) dataz;
System.out.println(dataz);


Object[]  obj1= new Object[5];
String[] strArray2 = new String[]{"Obj3","Array3","Converted3","To3","List3"};
String[] strArray3 = new String[]{"Obj4","Array4","Converted4","To4","List4"};
screen_dataz.put(0,(Object[]) strArray2);
screen_dataz.put(1,(Object[]) strArray3);
System.out.println("copying screen dataz to dataz");
dataz.putAll(screen_dataz);
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `dataz` and `screen_dataz` and explain what you mean by "it's not working".

Comment: Right, Until we have definition of `dataz`, a couple of answers below are arguably wrong !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not working because you're using the same keys (0 and 1) both in `dataz` and in `screen_dataz`.

According to the [official javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29), `putAll` "will replace any mappings that this map had for any of the keys currently in the specified map.", so you are now losing your previous objects contained in `dataz`.

Answer (score 17):

Make use of constructor and Shallow it .

```
dataz = new HashMap<Key,val>(screen_dataz);
```

Comment: This *might* be a solution. But perhaps `dataz` already has some useful data in it. Probably worth waiting until the OP defines the question more closely.

Comment: hey, do `screen_dataz` and `dataz` refer to the same location? As I tried this  and deleting values in `dataz` also deleted values from `screen_dataz`. I actually want to copy values from one map to a new map and not two variables referring to the same location.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply [construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-) a new one:

```
dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object>(screen_dataz);
```

Comment: beat you by 6 sec :) +1 :)

Comment: @Baadshah I'll take my revenge someday! Muahaha

Comment: As far as I can tell, you've both rushed in with something that might be correct. But you've made a big assumption that `dataz` can be overwritten.

Comment: The term *Copying* made me to post that.Let see if its addingnew or not :)

Comment: @DuncanJones The same reason made me post the answer too :) However, you might be right..

Answer (score 6):

```
Map tmp = new HashMap(patch);
tmp.keySet().removeAll(target.keySet());
target.putAll(tmp);
```

For detailed [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194522/how-to-putall-on-java-hashmap-contents-of-one-to-another-but-not-replace-existi)

Answer (score 3):

It's already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194522/how-to-putall-on-java-hashmap-contents-of-one-to-another-but-not-replace-existi)

```
Map tmp = new HashMap(patch);
tmp.keySet().removeAll(target.keySet());
target.putAll(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    HashMap<Integer,String> myMap=new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(1,"A");
    myMap.put(2,"B");
    HashMap<Integer,String> newMap=new HashMap<>();
    newMap.putAll(myMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> hash1 = new HashMap();
    hash1.put("one", "the firs one");
    hash1.put("two", "the second one");
    hash1.put("three", "the third one");
    HashMap<String, String> hash2 = new HashMap<>();
    hash2.putAll(hash1);
```