# Merge two Maps of Maps in Java

Tags: java, merge, hashmap

I have a HashMap which in turn has a HashMap within,

```java
Map<Long, Map<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I will have multiple inner maps for the same `Long` value, how do I make sure that the value field isn't replaced and rather merged (appended)?

This question differs from [How to putAll on Java hashMap contents of one to another, but not replace existing keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194522/) as it is about a Map of Strings, I'm stuck with a map of maps

For instance

```java
Map<Long, Map<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("1key1", 1.0);
map1.put("1key2", 2.0);
map1.put("1key3", 3.0);

map2.put("2key1", 4.0);
map2.put("2key2", 5.0);
map2.put("2key3", 6.0);

map.put(222l, map1);
map.put(222l, map2);
```

should give me 6 innermap entries for key **'222'** and not 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to putAll on Java hashMap contents of one to another, but not replace existing keys and values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194522/how-to-putall-on-java-hashmap-contents-of-one-to-another-but-not-replace-existi)

Comment: @JudeNiroshan The one that is mentioned is a simple String map, but I have a map within a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, instead of `put` you can call a [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
map.merge(222L, map2, (m1, m2) -> {m1.putAll(m2);return m1;});
```

If map already had a value corresponding to given key, the merge function passed as third argument will be called which just adds the content of the new map to the previously existing one. Here's complete code:

```
Map<Long, Map<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("1key1", 1.0);
map1.put("1key2", 2.0);
map1.put("1key3", 3.0);

map2.put("2key1", 4.0);
map2.put("2key2", 5.0);
map2.put("2key3", 6.0);

map.merge(222L, map1, (m1, m2) -> {m1.putAll(m2);return m1;});
map.merge(222L, map2, (m1, m2) -> {m1.putAll(m2);return m1;});
System.out.println(map);
```

Prints all six keys:

```
{222={1key2=2.0, 1key3=3.0, 2key3=6.0, 2key1=4.0, 1key1=1.0, 2key2=5.0}}
```

Comment: it still seems to give me only 3 values